# How do I disable a mvc razor @Html.TextBoxFor based on what is selected in a drop down menu on the same page?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-5

Let's say I have the following.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyWebPage, Model.FruitsList, "Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-select detailsInfo" })
```

And within this drop down menu I have a selection that says "Custom" and right after that drop down I have a textbox that is autopopulated with the user's already selected option

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyWebPage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id="CustomFruitTextBox"})
```

What would I have to call in order to disable the text box if the drop down selection is not currently selected to "Custom"?

Would this require javascript or could I do this in the razor file manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use js to check the selected value of the dropdown:
view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyWebPage, Model.FruitsList, "Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-select detailsInfo" @onchange="check()" })
```

js:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            check();
        })
        function check() {
            if ($("#MyWebPage").val() != "Custom") {
                $("#CustomFruitTextBox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else{
                $("#CustomFruitTextBox").removeAttr("disabled");

            }
            
        }
</script>
```